# mysql select condition with 3 conditions

Tags: mysql

I have table that have a field called **cheque_type** and this filed comes with 3 variables such as **Life,NonMotor,Motor**

And the table has a time stamp. I need to get a result that how many Life, Nonmotor , Motors checks are printed

**What i need is add another 3 columns to this sql query and get the number of results according to the category**

```
SELECT DATE(`timestamp`) As ___Date___,
COUNT(`id`) as Total,
SUM(print_status) as Printed,
(COUNT(`id`) - SUM(print_status)) as to_be_print
FROM cheque.vouchers
WHERE
DATE( `timestamp`)  >='2014-11-15'
AND DATE( `timestamp`)  <='2014-11-31'
group by DATE(`timestamp`) ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE(`timestamp`) As ___Date___,
       COUNT(`id`) as Total,
       SUM(print_status) as Printed,
       (COUNT(`id`) - SUM(print_status)) as to_be_print,
       sum(cheque_type = 'Life') as life_check,
       sum(cheque_type = 'NonMotor') as non_check,
       sum(cheque_type = 'Motor') as motor_check
FROM cheque.vouchers
WHERE DATE( `timestamp`)  >='2014-11-15'
AND DATE( `timestamp`)  <='2014-11-31'
group by DATE(`timestamp`) ;
```

Comment: Thanks,, your a life saver :)